# CRON job running but no sign of it in any file

Tags: linux, cron, ubuntu-10.04

This is an odd one and I know that the answer will be something simple that I have over looked... I have inherited responsibility for a Linux server running an old version of Ubuntu 10.04, it has a backup scrip running every hour but I can't find out where it's running from.

In the auth logs I see an entry every hour corresponding exactly to the time the backup is fired suggesting that this is a cron job:

```
"pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root"
```

It is not a remote command over SSH as there is no SSH session entry preceding it.

I have run the following command to list all user's cron jobs, which produces no results for anyone:

```
"for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done"
```

It's not anacron either... What else is there? Any suggestions on where I might look next? I am thinking potentially there is a GUI app and the auth log entry is misleading.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try also `/etc/cron.d/*`, `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/crontab`.

Answer (score 1):

The message comes from PAM which is consulted every time a shell is spawned. See contents of `/etc/pam.d`, especially files `/etc/pam.d/common-session` and `/etc/pam.d/cron`.

This message means that there is indeed a cronjob somewhere which is run by the root user. That does not mean the job is doing anything (it might, for example, just check if a certain logfile is big enough to be rotated and exit without rotating it).

Definitions of cronjobs are spread over several directories and files. For the root user you should take a look into file `/etc/crontab`, output of `crontab -l -u root` and contents of directories `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, `/etc/cron.monthly` and `/etc/cron.d`. The last one contains traditional cronjob definition tables whereas all the other directories contain executable scripts or binaries which are run by the cron with a period mentioned in the directory name (for more information see `man run-parts`).